# How to update the selected row in the listbox?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Hello so I'm trying to develop a UserForm and it's my first time.

[image: UI]

I'm having a problem with my ComboBox and ListBox (pretty much not functioning well).

You see, I have a ComboBox right above the ListBox and that's where I would choose a value and the row values should be displayed BOTH on the ListBox and the ComboBoxes.

**Problem 1:** The values only show in the ComboBoxes BUT NOT in the ListBox.

If I clicked on the "VIEW DATA" button, all the values from the spreadsheet are displayed on the ListBox with 8 columns. If clicked on a row from the ListBox (obviously it will be highlighted) it will also be displayed on the ComboBoxes below.

**Problem 2:** Whenever I try to edit the values in the ComboBox and click the update button, nothing happens. It doesn't update anything.

I'm looking for answers everywhere but I can't seem to find one.

```
     Private Sub btnDelete_Click()

        Dim a As Integer

            If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this row?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Yes") = vbYes Then

                For a = 1 To Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
                    If Cells(a, 1) = listHeader.List(listHeader.ListIndex) Then
                    Rows(a).Select
                    Selection.Delete
                End If
            Next a
        End If

    End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

'IM THINKING ABOUT REMOVING THE SEARCH BUTTON BECAUSE THE COMBOBOX ITSELF CAN BE USED FOR SEARCHING THE ROW
'IT MAKES THE SEARCH BUTTON USELESS

'Dim x As Long
'Dim y As Long

'x = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'For y = 2 To x

'If Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 1).Text = cmbSearch.Value Then
    'cmbSchema.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 1)
    'cmbEnvironment.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 2)
    'cmbHost.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 3)
    'cmbIP.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 4)
    'cmbAccessible.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 5)
    'cmbLast.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 6)
    'cmbConfirmation.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 7)
    'cmbProjects.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 8)

'End If
'Next y

End Sub

    Private Sub btnView_Click()

        listHeader.RowSource = "A4:H200"

    End Sub

Private Sub cmbAdd_Click()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PRESTAGE DB")

    nextrow = sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 1) = Me.cmbSchema
    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 2) = Me.cmbEnvironment
    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 3) = Me.cmbHost
    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 4) = Me.cmbIP
    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 5) = Me.cmbAccessible
    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 6) = Me.cmbLast
    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 7) = Me.cmbConfirmation
    sheet.Cells(nextrow, 8) = Me.cmbProjects

    MsgBox "Data Added!"

End Sub

Private Sub cmbClearFields_Click()

    cmbSchema.Text = ""
    cmbEnvironment.Text = ""
    cmbHost.Text = ""
    cmbIP.Text = ""
    cmbAccessible.Text = ""
    cmbLast.Text = ""
    cmbConfirmation.Text = ""
    cmbProjects.Text = ""
    cmbSearch.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub cmbSearch_Change()

Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

x = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For y = 2 To x

If Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 1).Text = cmbSearch.Value Then
    cmbSchema.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 1)
    cmbEnvironment.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 2)
    cmbHost.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 3)
    cmbIP.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 4)
    cmbAccessible.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 5)
    cmbLast.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 6)
    cmbConfirmation.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 7)
    cmbProjects.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 8)

End If
Next y

End Sub

    Private Sub cmbUpdate_Click()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

    x = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For y = 2 To x
    If Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 1).Text = cmbSchema.Value Then
    Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 2) = cmbEnvironment
    Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 3) = cmbHost
    Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 4) = cmbIP
    Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 5) = cmbAccessible
    Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 6) = cmbLast
    Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 7) = cmbConfirmation
    Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 8) = cmbProjects

    End If
    Next y

    End Sub

    Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
        listHeader.RowSource = ""

    End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()

End Sub

    Private Sub listHeader_Click()

        cmbSchema.Value = UserForm1.listHeader.Column(0)
        cmbEnvironment.Value = UserForm1.listHeader.Column(1)
        cmbHost.Value = UserForm1.listHeader.Column(2)
        cmbIP.Value = UserForm1.listHeader.Column(3)
        cmbAccessible.Value = UserForm1.listHeader.Column(4)
        cmbLast.Value = UserForm1.listHeader.Column(5)
        cmbConfirmation.Value = UserForm1.listHeader.Column(6)
        cmbProjects.Value = UserForm1.listHeader.Column(7)

    End Sub


    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

        cmbSearch.List = Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Range("A4:A10000").Value

    End Sub
```

file: https://jmp.sh/cZj8e4q

Comment: Can you share the excel file?

Comment: hello 0m3r, i added a link to the file thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code for **Problem1**

Used Change event for combobox so if user changes any value the list box and combo box will be populated based on the value selected in the combo box.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    x = Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For y = 2 To x
        If Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 1).Text = ComboBox1.Value Then
            cmbSchema.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 1)
            cmbEnvironment.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 2)
            cmbHost.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 3)
            cmbIP.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 4)
            cmbAccessible.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 5)
            cmbLast.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 6)
            cmbConfirmation.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 7)
            cmbProjects.Text = Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 8)

            UserForm1.ListBox1.RowSource = "A" + CStr(y) + ": H" + CStr(y)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next y
End Sub
```

Please accept if resolves your issue

Comment: HEY THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! THE FIRST PROBLEM WORKED!! However, the problem 2 isn't working yet. nothing happens whever i click the UPDATE BTN.

Comment: but thank you so much for the 1st problem tho!! You are so good!

Comment: Express your appreciation by accepting and upvoting helpful answers :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hellooo I upvoted it but stackoverflow prompts "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

For **Problem2**

Use .Value to get the value from the field and then set the value to the spread sheet -> cmbEnvironment.Value

```
Private Sub cmbUpdate_Click()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

    x = Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For y = 2 To x
        If Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 1).Text = cmbSchema.Value Then
            Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 2) = cmbEnvironment.Value
            Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 3) = cmbHost.Value
            Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 4) = cmbIP.Value
            Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 5) = cmbAccessible.Value
            Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 6) = cmbLast.Value
            Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 7) = cmbConfirmation.Value
            Sheets("PRESTAGEDB").Cells(y, 8) = cmbProjects.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next y
End Sub
```

When i Change the value in the combobox it is set the updated value in the cell. Please debug the code and share the details if not working.

Comment: Hello, I don't know if I'm correct but I copied your code and still nothing happens. My original code was cmbEnvironment so i added .Value in the end but nothing still works. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't get any errors tho. it just happen that whenever i try to update the value in he combobox it, it is still not updated on the list/spreadsheet. It just goes back to it's own value.

Comment: Try clicking the "VIEW DATA" button and all the details in the spreadsheet are displayed. What i'm trying to do is that I will click a row from the listbox and edit the value to the combobox and save it using the Update button. However, it doesn't work. I'm still trying to figure it out. I appreciate all the help from you, VENKATESH. Many thanks!

Comment: I have changed the work sheet name so use you original code and append .Value. Sheets("PRESTAGE DB").Cells(y, 2) in Add watch and check the value is get changed when respective code is executed.

Comment: ohhh i see the problem now. It only works on the cmbEnvironment column but not in any other columns. I was typing on PROJECTS combobox but it didn't work.

Comment: it only allows me to edit the Environment column but not the HOST to PROJECTS

Comment: Have verified. It is worked fine for me. I gone to Macro window (Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications). Pressed F5 from key board. Selected "L_MA_MEMRE/MDCOREDI" from Combo box which is at top left. Entered the value "Test" Environment combobox and 'N' in Accessible combo box. Clicked "Update Row". The details are updated in the spread sheet. Please let me know if i missing something here

Comment: Please check whether multiple spread sheet opened. If so please close the other excel sheet and try it.